# Wix—Operation (setFilter) not allowed on write-only dataset

Tags: velo

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx7_8-lRsW0

But I'm hitting an error:

`Operation (setFilter) not allowed on write-only dataset`

Can someone explain how datasets work, and how I can execute `.setFilter()`?

My code:

```
import wixData from "wix-data";

$w.onReady(function () {
    wixData.query('collectionName');
});

let debounceTimer;
export function iTitle_keyPress(event, $w) {
    console.log('hello');
    if(debounceTimer) {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
        debounceTimer = undefined;
    }
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        filter($w('#iTitle').value);
    }, 200);
}

let lastFilterTitle;
function filter(title) {
    console.log(title);
    if(lastFilterTitle !== title) {
        $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter().contains('name',title));
        lastFilterTitle = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mode of your dataset from the dataset settings panel. A write-only dataset is used for things like a user input form. Here, since you're using your dataset to display data, you want a read-only dataset.